# How can I launch an ssh session by clicking on a link on a web page?

Tags: ssh, browser

Say I have a webpage with something like:

```
<a href="ssh://foo@bar.com">foo@bar.com</a>
```

Is there any way to have it launch an ssh terminal?

My preference is that this works on Ubuntu with Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want *your* machine to launch SSH, then you need to change the protocol handler for ssh in your operating system.

There is an example of setting up a protocol handler in Ubuntu [here](http://www.tkalin.com/blog_posts/using-console-vim-as-vim-protocol-handler-in-ubuntu).  In Windows you need to alter the registry.

Web sites can't make visitors open client-side custom handlers; it would be a security risk.  But a page can have Mozilla and Firefox register a web service as a protocol handler.  Documentation for that is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/navigator.registerProtocolHandler).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting up the command in a .cgi script.

Comment: Care to expand on how to do this exactly?

Comment: Put an executable script in the website server designated cgi area (or name it with *.cgi extension).  Make sure your configuration allows for CGI scripts.  And finally remember that the script will be executing as the apache user!

Comment: PS: try looking at the CGI tutorial and mod_cgi info on the apache website.

Comment: Thanks for expanding on your answer; but, when you do that (expand on an answer), it makes sense to do it by editing the answer rather than posting a reply comment.  Also, providing a link to the tutorial would be useful.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. This guy isn't trying to run a command on the server...